# How to set an specific date?

Tags: php, mktime

I'm trying to create an date with

```
$date_end = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+7, date('Y'), $date_set);
```

The output is today + 7 days instead of the date given + 7.

Comment: `date('d')` returns today's day, then `+ 7` would return 7 days from today. What are you trying to do? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: That's because `date()` returns parts of today's date.  How are you specifying the reference date?

Answer (score 3):

[The manual says nothing about `mktime()` taking a date as argument](http://dk.php.net/mktime).

Use `strtotime("+7 days", $date_set)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date_end = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $date_set), date('d', $date_set)+7, date('Y', $date_set));
```

is, I believe, what you were trying to accomplish (assuming `$date_set` is a timestamp). Else, @Kristian's suggestion I believe is a good one.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you passing a `$date_set` variable, and why are you using `mktime` if you already have the time?

Simply add 7 days: `$date_end = $date_set + (7 * 86400);`

Comment: If you want to add exactly 7 days, use this. If you count for summer time, it's not exactly 7 days anymore.